# How can I mount or unmount the SD Card using ADB?

Tags: sd-card, adb, mount

The sdcard can be umounted by using the umount command.

```
unmount /mtn/sdcard/.android_secure
```

how can it be remounted again . I tried using the mount command

```
mount /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure
```

Answer (score 6):

Connect your device and at the command prompt:

Type `adb devices` & press enter (Your device should now be listed)...

Type `adb shell` & press enter (Wait for the "#" to appear)....

Type `mount sdcard` next to the "#" sign & press enter...

You will need to know the mount point also if you intend to mount the external card.

As an example:

> su
>   mount -o bind /mnt/emmc /sdcard/external_sd

Comment: I face sh: unmount: not found , I have transformer tf 101

Comment: Bit of a delayed comment, but in unix environments it's "umount" not "unmount". How did they not see this would confuse so many people I do not know.

Comment: @forsubhi, as Gessh_SO said, "umount", not "unmount".

Comment: can sombody help me out? I'm encountering the similar case but have no luck @Sparx 
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164843/sd-memory-and-internal-memory-get-unmounted-automatically